# Unexpected token } at the end of json response

Tags: json, grails

I store json object as varchar in database.

There strange thing is that excess ending brace is added to the end of the only one of my json objects(from thousands).

I see the bug in chrome & firefox. In firefox console error is the following:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data.
>   In chrome the error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token }

While debugging I assured that myjson string that i return from grails controller is without that excessed `'}'`.

I render json from controller by the following code:

```
render(text:shape?.geojson, contentType:"application/json", encoding:"UTF-8")
```

Also, the problem is not in javascript, as i get not valid json by get request.

What could be the cause of such a strange behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it stored in the db with the extra brace ?

Comment: Why would you want to store a JSON object as a field? I can't think of a case that is worth doing that. Load your data from different columns, create a proper object and serialize it to JSON. Most probably the string that represents JSON in the DB is not properly constructed.

Comment: @SteveP no, it is without extra brace

Comment: @ikaros45 it is geospatial data, valid geojson string. It`s not rationally to create 100mb geojson dynamically.

Comment: When storing JSON as string, you lose completely control over your data. If you don't consider acceptable creating objects and serializing them, you should at least consider using an object oriented DB.

Comment: @ikaros45 my data is static and doesn`t change in time. Don`t you save static data in the db? It is out of the question to discuss data model of the project, the problem is that i have valid json that is added with extra closing brace when rendering.

Comment: You can consider caching the return of the controller instead of storing the json in the database. Grails have a cache plugin, take a look: http://grails.org/plugin/cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed after I set contentType:"text/json" instead of "application/json"

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, I have a spring controller and it puts extra } at the end of the json when I make ajax calls, funny thing is when I do curl instead of browser, it does not put an extra '}'. The other fix I found was putting dataType as jsonp instead of json, but I am not sure why I have to do that, is there a limit on datatype json or contentType application/json? Also I do not store json, its coming from an API so a regular dto is converted into json